# how can I create a loop in my html tag to show all the JSON child fields in my database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a survey application connected to a Firebase database. For reference, firebase database uses a JSON structure. Below is a snippet of my database:

[image: JSON Structure]

I've got the right child showing in my console (questions), but I am only able to show the value in my html header once. The header doesn't loop and show each question on the HTML page, although I can see them in console. Here's where I need your help. I have no clue how to loop an HTML tag to show that data. I searched the internet for a while but haven't been able to find the right solution. Below is the code I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DAILY SURVEY REMINDER</title>

</head>
<body>

<div>

<h id = questions> </h1>

</div>




</body>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"> . 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase- 
functions.js"></script>
<script>

// Initialize Firebase

var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyCOUA9eYXRgrStbMXx-bcE2lR7e5IYjP2g",
authDomain: "testingdb-a8cd7.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://testingdb-a8cd7.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "testingdb-a8cd7",
storageBucket: "testingdb-a8cd7.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "384953133465"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
var question = document.getElementById('questions');
window.onload = function getData(){
for(  i = 1; i < 35; i++){

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Questions/'+i).child('questions');
dbRef.on('value', snap => { question.innerText = 
JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
console.log(snap.val());
question = snap.val();
});
}

};




</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you currently load a question you run this code with it:

```
question = snap.val();
```

This means that you're replacing the `questions` element with the latest question every time, which explains why you only see the last question in the end.

If you have a list of questions it's better to work with an element that is meant to contain a list, for example an ordered list (`<ol>`). Then for each question you insert an additional `<li>` into it with that question.

The HMTL element:

```
<ol id="questions"> </ol>
```

And then the code:

```
var question = document.getElementById('questions');
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Questions');
window.onload = function getData(){
  for(i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
    dbRef.child(i+'/questions').once('value', snap => { 
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = snap.val();
      question.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
};
```

If you want to show *all* questions instead of specifically the first 35, you can simply let Firebase call you for all child nodes:

```
var question = document.getElementById('questions');
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Questions');
window.onload = function getData(){
  dbRef.on('child_added', snap => { 
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = snap.val().questions;
    question.appendChild(li);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally understand how the snap=> works. Your explanation is GOLD.

Comment: I do need to iterate between the whole list, but for each of these questions, I will either have multiple choice answers, or a textbox. The multiple choice questions will also need to be pulled from firebase. Those will be under a new root "answers". Could you guide me how to best do that?

Comment: If they follow the same approach, it'll really just be more of the same type of code. But I have a feeling you're learning both how to manipulate  HTML and how to read from Firebase at the same time here. It's best to focus on one thing at a time: either read from Firebase and just log it out to the console (with `console.log(...)`) or hard-code the JSON in your JavaScript file and focus on how to generate HTML elements from it. You'll also find that it's much easier to find tutorials for each separate part, than it is to find for the combination.

Comment: Thanks. yeah you are right, its hard to find tutorials on both. Also, just ran the code, it still working the same way. console logs the right questions, but the html just shows just one question.

Comment: My code doesn't log anything to the console, and shouldn't overwrite the HTML. You might want to double check if you copied it correctly. I also recommend studying each line and learning about each call in there. E.g. [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`li.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), [`question.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). I minimized the number of methods I used, precisely to make it as easy as possible to follow along.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the logic to:

```
dbRef.on('value', snap => { 
    question.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>' + snap.val() + '</p>');
});
```

Please give a try and let us know.